# gdb can't find a symbol to break on

Tags: c++, gdb

I am debugging a C++ application, `info shared` tells me this library I want to break in has been read and has debugging symbols,

```
0x00007fffedc1f530  0x00007ffff18e4e60  Yes         /home/me/WPEWebKit/WebKitBuild/Debug/lib/libWPEWebKit.so
```

I then ran `nm` on this loaded shared library and found a symbol I would like to break on (just to make sure the name was right):

```
$ nm /home/me/WPEWebKit/WebKitBuild/Debug/lib/libWPEWebKit.so | c++filt | grep -iw handleSyncmessage
0000000008a03e14 T WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamer::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)
```

It might be worth me saying that `libWPEWebKit.so` is just over 650MB, so quite a heavyweight.

Now in GDB, I say this,

```
(gdb) break WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamer::handleSyncMessage
Function "WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamer::handleSyncMessage" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])
```

But we know at this point the symbol is loaded. If I rerun with the breakpoint set, it never gets fired, despite having proved the function is indeed running.

Am I doing something wrong here?

*Edit: Adding info functions output*

```
(gdb) info functions handleSyncMessage
All functions matching regular expression "handleSyncMessage":

.. lots of template instantiations I am ommitting because they are from unrelated things that just ref. this type ..

File ../../Source/WebCore/platform/graphics/gstreamer/MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamer.cpp:
bool (anonymous namespace)::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamer::handleSyncMessage(GstMessage*);

File ../../Source/WebCore/platform/graphics/gstreamer/MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase.cpp:
bool (anonymous namespace)::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(GstMessage*);

..

Non-debugging symbols:
0x00007fffed84bcf0  WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)@plt
0x00007fffed84d810  WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamer::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)@plt
```

I now notice that I missed some output from nm above that I add for completeness

```
0000000008a03e14 T WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamer::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)
0000000008a11868 T WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)
0000000008a16fa8 t std::remove_reference<WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)::{lambda()#1}&>::type&& std::move<WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)::{lambda()#1}&>(std::remove_reference&&)
0000000008a16f78 t WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)::{lambda()#1}& std::forward<WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)::{lambda()#1}&>(std::remove_reference<WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)::{lambda()#1}&>::type&)
0000000008a17959 t WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)::{lambda()#1}&& std::forward<WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)::{lambda()#1}>(std::remove_reference<WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)::{lambda()#1}>::type&)
000000000bdac7d0 r WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)::__FUNCTION__
000000000bdac800 r WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)::__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
0000000008a11834 t WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)::{lambda()#2}::operator()() const
0000000008a115a4 t WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)::{lambda()#1}::operator()() const
0000000008a18128 t WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)::{lambda()#1}::_GstMessage({lambda()#1}&&)
0000000008a18128 t WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)::{lambda()#1}::_GstMessage({lambda()#1}&&)
0000000008a117f8 t WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)::{lambda()#1}::~_GstMessage()
0000000008a117f8 t WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)::{lambda()#1}::~_GstMessage()
000000000bdaddc8 r WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)::{lambda()#1}::operator()() const::__FUNCTION__
```

I tried breaking on the `MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase` symbol as well as the `MediaMediaPlayerPrivateGStreamer` symbol to no success.

*Edit 2*

Another attempt,

```
(gdb) rbreak ^WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7fffed84bcf0
<function, no debug info> WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)@plt;
```

So I guess the underlying question is why does GDB only set breaks on the procedure linkage table and not the real library function? How people even debug on Linux platforms? This seems utterly insane. Needless to say, even the breakpoint on the plt entry is not firing..

Comment: I think you need to give a full function name with the signature, as nm reports. Have yoy tried tab completion to retrieve the correct name?

Comment: Copying all the line also does not work (incl. the function parameters). Tab completion completes the form with the function parameters, but I get the same message about it not being defined (despite it being completed automatically!)

Comment: Hmm that's strange. Are you using the latest gdb?

Comment: Does the gdb command `info functions handleSyncMessage` show anything?

Comment: This is gdb 8.0.1, I would expect basic method breakpointing to have been working for some time.. :) @MarkPlotnick , thanks for that, I edited my question with its output, it made me notice I have not given all the information that was available in the nm output, but I'm still unsure what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you both very much for your help BTW!

Comment: I just noticed that `rbreak ^WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase` matched `<function, no debug info> WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamerBase::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)@plt;`, maybe my mistake was missing `@plt`. No debug info sounds worrying though.

Comment: Nope, no breakpoints hit sadly.

Comment: Try `break 'WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateGStreamer::handleSyncMessage(_GstMessage*)'`

Comment: @ks1322, nope, that was an previous attempt, it claims the function is not defined.

Comment: Can you put any breakpoint on a C++ function in any shared library?

Comment: @n.m. not that I can tell, it only selects the '@plt' members which don't hit breakpoints when I use something like rbreak

Comment: I'm asking, does it happen with all shared libraries or only this particular one?

Comment: "How people even debug on Linux platforms?" part of the question is counter-productive -- it turns off the very people who are most likely to be able to help you. The answer is usually: just fine, works for me.

Comment: @EmployedRussian That is true, I shouldn't have said that.

Comment: `info shared` confusingly only really says whether it tried to read debug info, not whether it actually exists.  I would double-check the .so to make sure debuginfo is really there.

Comment: Ah, I see now that there is debuginfo and that the method is in an anonymous namespace.  Try `break '..exactly what info func output...'` -- with the single quotes.